# Trying to build a docker image, but cannot run mkdir in Docker file

Tags: python, docker

For context, I am relatively inexperienced with docker. I am currently trying to build a docker image from the root directory of a python project. Using this command:

```
docker build --no-cache  --build-arg USER_ID=012023 --build-arg GROUP_ID=012023 -t traffic-control:latest C:\Users\name\github\rl_traffic_control\traffic_control
```

This results in the following error:

```
1292.9 Makefile:140: recipe for target 'all' failed
1292.9 make: *** [all] Error 2
------
Dockerfile:25
--------------------
  24 |     ENV SUMO_HOME=sumo-1.18.0
  25 | >>> RUN mkdir sumo-1.18.0/build/cmake-build && cd sumo-1.18.0/build/cmake-build \
  26 | >>>     && cmake ../.. && make -j$(nproc)
  27 |
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/bash -c mkdir sumo-1.18.0/build/cmake-build && cd sumo-1.18.0/build/cmake-build     && cmake
```

For context here is the code from the dockerfile in question:

```
RUN curl https://sumo.dlr.de/releases/1.18.0/sumo-src-1.18.0.tar.gz \
    | tar -xz
ENV SUMO_HOME=sumo-1.18.0
RUN mkdir sumo-1.18.0/build/cmake-build && cd sumo-1.18.0/build/cmake-build \
    && cmake ../.. && make -j$(nproc)
```

I am doing all of this through the terminal in visual studio code. I'm not sure what the issue is here this error message isn't really giving me much.

I have tried re-running the build without the caches to no success. It's difficult for me to find the root of my problem with my limited knowledge in this case.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What happens if you just start with the ```RUN mkdir sumo-1.18.0/build/cmake-build```?  If ```sumo-1.18.0/build``` doesn't exist, you'd get an error.

Comment: @ewokx, that worked. I was able to build the image rather quickly. What revision do I need to make to the omitted part in order to make it work?

Comment: The first line in the error suggests to me that the `make` part of the command was running and failing, so the `mkdir` and `cmake` steps ran successfully.  The actual error is probably in the page or two of error before that.

Comment: It's definitely my make -j command. I don't understand why though.